# document.readyState is always 'loading' when using karma and jasmine & PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have a bunch of commonjs javascript modules. One of them interacts with the document javascript global. To keep everything modular and testable, I've created a couple of modules that contain the document and window objects.

```
// document.js
module.exports = document;

// window.js
module.exports = window;
```

My module placeholderReplacer.js then includes this as a dependency

```
// palceholderReplacer.js
var document = require('./document');
var window = require('./window');

// replacePlaceholders() & a bunch of private methods live here...

var placeholderReplacer = {
  replace: function() {
    var prerequisitesAvailable = function() {
      return document.addEventListener && document.getElementsByClassName && XMLHttpRequest;
    };

    if (prerequisitesAvailable()) {
      if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        replacePlaceholders();
      } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          replacePlaceholders();
        }, false);
      }
    }
  }
};
module.exports = placeholderReplacer;
```

The problem I have is that when I run my unit tests on Karma with PhantomJS and Jasmine, the `document.readyState` is always **loading** and replacePlaceholders() is never called. The event listener is not being called either as I'm suspecting it's too late.

For simplicity, I've removed all the tests from placeholderReplacerTest.js, and I just have:

```
var $ = require('../vendor/jquery'),
  placeholderReplacer = require('../modules/placeholderReplacer');

placeholderReplacer.replace();
```

I'm pretty new at javascript unit testing and CommonJS modules so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have managed to achieve this is by setting a global function to return the value of `document.readyState` and mocking this in the test. Granted its not the best solution but as you cannot change the readyState [Is it possible to change document.readyState with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947982/is-it-possible-to-change-document-readystate-with-javascript) this is the best work around I have come up with.

So in your javascript file, add a window function to return the value of document.readyState;

```
 // palceholderReplacer.js
var document = require('./document');
var window = require('./window');

// Add this
window.getReadyState = function(){
    return document.readyState;
}

// replacePlaceholders() & a bunch of private methods live here...

var placeholderReplacer = {
  replace: function() {
    var prerequisitesAvailable = function() {
      return document.addEventListener && document.getElementsByClassName && XMLHttpRequest;
    };

    if (prerequisitesAvailable()) {
      // change this also
      if (window.getReadyState() == "complete") {
        replacePlaceholders();
      } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          replacePlaceholders();
        }, false);
      }
    }
  }
};
module.exports = placeholderReplacer;
```

And in your test, mock the return value of this global function before you run the test;

```
var $ = require('../vendor/jquery'),
  placeholderReplacer = require('../modules/placeholderReplacer');

it('should return value complete', function(){
    window.getReadyState = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue("complete");
    placeholderReplacer.replace();
});

it('should return value loading', function(){
    window.getReadyState = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue("loading");
    placeholderReplacer.replace();
});
```

Hope this helps or if you found the answer could you please respond